# how to convert this constructor to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Do not know how to convert `Me.Base` to C#

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic  

Public Class ReplaceHTML  
    Inherits System.IO.Stream  

    Private Base As System.IO.Stream  

    Public Sub New(ByVal ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream)  
        If ResponseStream Is Nothing Then 
           Throw New ArgumentNullException("ResponseStream")  
        Me.Base = ResponseStream  
    End Sub  
End Class
```

full code is [here](http://aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-Response.Filter-to-intercept-your-HTML)

thanks!

Comment: What does the rest of the class and the parent class look like? Are you sure Base isn't just a property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using `this.Base`

`this` tells it to use the current instance of the class

**Edit:**

with your updated question i think it should look more like

```
public class ReplaceHTML : System.IO.Stream
{
    private System.IO.Stream Base;
    public ReplaceHTML(System.IO.Stream ResponseStream)
    {
        if (ResponseStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ResponseStream");
        }
        this.Base = ResponseStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the last line if it seems condescending, had to make it 30 characters

Comment: compile error: Error 1 'ReplaceHTML' does not contain a definition for 'Base' and no extension method 'Base' accepting a first argument of type 'ReplaceHTML' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: thanks everyone! base on [this article]( http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters), looks like Base is a property.

Comment: @Dean see edited version, by the way for quite a few vb to c# convertions http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ is quite useful, i just tried it and it seems to be able to convert the full code you linked quite well

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public YourClass(System.IO.Stream ResponseStream)
{
    if (ResponseStream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ResponseStream");
    }
    // the "this" is optional here but I left it to show
    // that it is the equivalent of VB's "Me"
    this.Base = ResponseStream;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.Base
```

That should be Me.Base